# Confused with 3 versions of OAuth 1.0 consumers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnetopenauth

**My goal:** Using one click and redirection, I want a user to login to my site and give me authorization (accessToken) to his Gmail. I thought to use **A** (DNOA) to authorize + upgrade to accessToken.

But DNOA wasn't so clear to me so I used another dll (http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/) in **B**.

Then I realized I want the user to be authenticated + authorized the second time he comes to my site so without redirecting him again to "site X asks for permissions to you Gmail page".

I understand I have to use both OpenID and OAuth. So I used the code in **C**.

Despite all of the above I'm confused and not sure which code fits the most to my needs.

Maybe none of the fits?
How can I check them on localhost? (see code comment in **C**)

Any light you can shed will be thankful!

**A:**

```
 public void PrepareAuthorizationRequest(Uri authCallbakUrl)
        {
            var consumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumerConsts.ServiceDescription, mConsumerTokenManager);

            var requestParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                        {
                                            {"scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email"}};

            // request access
            consumer.Channel.Send(consumer.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(authCallbakUrl, requestParameters, null));

            // throw new NoRedirectToAuthPageException();
        }

        public ProcessAuthorizationRequestResponse ProcessAuthorizationRequest()
        {
            ProcessAuthorizationRequestResponse response;
            // Process result from the service provider
            var consumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumerConsts.ServiceDescription, mConsumerTokenManager);
            var accessTokenResponse = consumer.ProcessUserAuthorization();

            // If we didn't have an access token response, this wasn't called by the service provider
            if (accessTokenResponse == null)
                response = new ProcessAuthorizationRequestResponse
                               {
                                   IsAuthorized = false
                               };
            else
            {
                // Extract the access token
                string accessToken = accessTokenResponse.AccessToken;
                response = new ProcessAuthorizationRequestResponse
                 {
                     IsAuthorized = true,
                     Token = accessToken,
                     Secret = mConsumerTokenManager.GetTokenSecret(accessToken)
                 };
            }
            return response;
        }
```

**B:**

```
public void GetAuthorizeRequestToken(OAuthProviderTypes authType)
{
    var consumer = mAuthorizationConsumerFactory.GetConsumer(authType);
    requestToken = GetRequestToken(consumer);
    AuthorizeRequestToken(requestToken, consumer);
}

public AccessToken UpgradeToAccessToken(OAuthProviderTypes authType, RequestToken requestToken)
{
    var consumer = mAuthorizationConsumerFactory.GetConsumer(authType);
    var oAuthConsumer = new OAuthConsumer();
    var accessToken = oAuthConsumer.GetOAuthAccessToken(consumer.AccessTokenEndpoint, _realm, consumer.ConsumerKey, consumer.ConsumerSecret, consumer.Token, consumer.Verifier, requestToken.TokenSecret);
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("~/Authentication.htm?google");
    // Google Only - This method will get the email of the authenticated user
    //var responseText = oAuthConsumer.GetUserInfo("https://www.googleapis.com/userinfo/email", realm, consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken.Token, accessToken.TokenSecret);
    return new AccessToken();
}


private RequestToken GetRequestToken(IConsumer consumer)
{
    var oAuthConsumer = new OAuthConsumer();

    var requestToken = oAuthConsumer.GetOAuthRequestToken(consumer.RequestTokenEndpoint, _realm,
                                                          consumer.ConsumerKey, consumer.ConsumerSecret,
                                                          consumer.RequestTokenCallback);
    // PersistRequestToken(requestToken);

    return requestToken;
}

private void AuthorizeRequestToken(RequestToken requestToken, IConsumer consumer)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(consumer.AuthorizeTokenUrl + "?oauth_token=" + requestToken.Token);
}
```

**C:**

```
private IAuthenticationRequest GetGoogleRequest()
        {
            // Google requires that the realm and consumer key be equal,
            // so we constrain the realm to match the realm in the web.config file.
            // This does mean that the return_to URL must also fall under the key,
            // which means this sample will only work on a public web site
            // that is properly registered with Google.
            // We will customize the realm to use http or https based on what the
            // return_to URL will be (which will be this page).

            var consumer = new WebConsumer(GoogleConsumerConsts.ServiceDescription, mConsumerTokenManager);

            //Realm realm = "http://localhost:8976/";
            Realm realm = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Scheme + Uri.SchemeDelimiter + consumer.ConsumerKey + "/";
            IAuthenticationRequest authReq = GoogleConsumerConsts.RelyingParty.CreateRequest(GoogleConsumerConsts.GoogleOPIdentifier, realm);

            // Prepare the OAuth extension
            string scope = GoogleConsumerConsts.GetScopeUri(GoogleConsumerConsts.Applications.Contacts);
            consumer.AttachAuthorizationRequest(authReq, scope);

            // We also want the user's email address
            var fetch = new FetchRequest();
            fetch.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
            authReq.AddExtension(fetch);

            return authReq;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach **C** seems most correct given your requirements.  However, do *not* set your Realm's scheme (http vs https) based on the current request.  For Google, the OpenID realm absolutely must be the same all the time (HTTPS always, since that's an option for you) otherwise your users will be assigned different claimed identifiers when they log in and have *two* accounts on your site (one for HTTP and one for HTTPS) which is not what you want.

And yes, given Google's OAuth design you'll have to have a publicly addressible domain in your URL to test it out.  Sad, but true, regardless of which OAuth consumer library you might go with.

I suggest that you use **C**, adjusted as described above, and modify it so that it gracefully degrades when run on `localhost` so that you have a local dev box story for testing.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can you please explain again "gracefully degrades when run on localhost". How would you suggest to degrade?

Comment: "Google's OAuth design you'll have to have a publicly addressible domain in your URL to test it out". i have downloaded http://www.matlus.com/oauth-c-library/ and tried on localhost successfully

Comment: Do you use the localhost realm with the matlus library when you see it working?  I thought the realm had to equal the consumer_key you've registered with Google, so I'm surprised that worked.

Comment: Yes, localhost realm with the matlus.